# OpenVPN: Only Allow Access Specific Client Network

Tags: linux, iptables, openvpn

OpenVPN: Limiting Client Access to Specific Destination Clients
I have two OpenVPN client (ovpn_dest1, ovpn_dest2) which run continuously and have a private network (10.60.10.0/24 & 10.60.20.0/24) which I want to access from two Windows OpenVPN clients.

The windows OpenVPN clients (ovpn_user1, ovpn_user2) however should only be able to access their respective networks (either 10.60.10.0/24 or 10.60.20.0/24).

With ovpn_user1 access to ovpn_dest1 (10.60.10.0/24) and ovpn_user2 should only able to access ovpn_dest2 (10.60.20.0/24).

The current setup uses the client-to-client directive in the host OpenVPN server.conf file, which is needed to allow the Windows clients to talk to the ovpn_dest1/2 and their network devices (device1_1/device1_2/etc).

Unfortunately this client-to-client directive means that a Windows client can also access all ovpn_dest1/2 clients which is not wanted from a security point of view.

Network and IP designations:

```
ovpn_dest1 - 10.60.10.2
  device1_1  - 10.60.10.3
  device1_2  - 10.60.10.4
ovpn_dest2 - 10.60.20.2
  device2_1  - 10.60.20.3

ovpn_user1 - 10.60.10.0/24
ovpn_user2 - 10.60.20.0/24
```

/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf:

```
local 188.166.226.159
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 67.207.67.3"
push "dhcp-option DNS 67.207.67.2"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log

client-to-client
client-config-dir ccd
```

/etc/openvpn/server/ccd/ovpn_dest1

```
route 10.60.10.0 255.255.255.0
iroute 10.60.10.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.60.10.0 255.255.255.0"
```

/etc/openvpn/server/ccd/ovpn_dest2

```
route 10.60.20.0 255.255.255.0
iroute 10.60.20.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.60.20.0 255.255.255.0"
```

I can also connect to all of the following devices from any windows OpenVPN client (ovpn_user1/ovpn_user2):

```
http://10.8.0.2/   (ovpn_dest1)
http://10.8.0.3/   (ovpn_dest2)
http://10.60.10.2/ (ovpn_dest1)
http://10.60.20.2/ (ovpn_dest2)
10.60.10.3 (device1_1)
```

However I want to limit the access for windows clients such that a given client can only access its specific ovpn_destN network.

I have tried using iptables, however I am no expert in this, and it seems the client-to-client directive in the server.conf file effectively overrides anything attempted in iptables to block a route between a source and destination. (The directive "client to client networking will be done inside OpenVPN without reaching host layer"). It seems I might have to remove "client-to-client" from the server.conf to limit connections, but I have been unable to establish communications when this line is removed.

I have considered using multiple OpenVPN instances (one for each set of ovpn_destN, ovpn_userN) however with many dozens of instances this may not be ideal. Although multiple networks will likely not be accessed frequently concurrently.

What (and how) is the best way of limiting a Windows client to a specific destination network?

Comment: How do the clients get their IP addresses?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Sorry, not quite sure what you mean by that. I have an ipp.txt file which is automatically populated when new clients join, but this isn't really relevant I assume.

Answer (score 0):

Since your configuration contains `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"`, it means that OpenVPN clients will set their default gateway to the address of OpenVPN server.

This means that all client traffic is forwarded to the OpenVPN server. Therefore the `ccd` configurations are meaningless, because those routes are covered by the default route.

First, make sure that your clients are assigned static IP addresses. Add the following line to the `ovpn_dest1` file in the server `ccd` directory for the client:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0
```

And respectively to `ovpn_dest2`:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.3 255.255.255.0
```

Then configure firewall on OpenVPN server as follows:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.2 -d 10.60.20.2 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.3 -d 10.60.10.2 -j DROP
```

First one blocks traffic from client 1 to destination 2 and second one from client 2 to destination 1.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, but are you saying to add `ifconfig-push 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0` to the client's .ovpn configuration file or to the server's server.conf file? 
Also, should the "client-to-client" line be removed from the server.conf file then as this will otherwise make iptable rules likely have no effect?

Comment: Just to clarify, ovpn_user1 and ovpn_user2 are the Windows users which should have access to the networks 10.60.10.0/24 and 10.60.20.0/24 respectively.

Comment: These lines should be added on the server side to the files in `ccd` directory, so they are client specific configurations.

Comment: Should the `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` and `client-to-client` directives remain, or should they both be removed?

Comment: The default gateway push should be removed at least.